# How to interpolate in React

Tags: reactjs, interpolation, src

I have an attribute **src** in *img* *src="images/education.jpg"*.
Images are written in the **object**.

```
const itemData = [
  {
    img: "image",
    title: "Education",
    src: "education.jpg",
  },
  {
img: "image2",
    title: "Cooking",
    src: "cooking.jpg",
},
];
```

How to interpolate this string like `src="images/{item.src}"` I know, this is incorrect.

```
 {itemData.map((item) => (
      <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
        <img            
        src="images/education.jpg"
        />
```

Comment: `src={\`images/${itemData[i].src}\`}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
{itemData.map((item, i) => (
  <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
    <img src={"images/" + itemData[i].src} />
  </ImageListItem>
)}
```

Or another way you can do:

```
{itemData.map((item, i) => (
  <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
    <img src={`images/${itemData[i].src}`} />
  </ImageListItem>
)}
```